# Apache VirtualDocumentRoot offset more than 10 characters

Tags: apache-2.4, apache-2.2

I am using **mod_vhost_alias** and trying to use a VirtualDocumentRoot where the offset is more than 10 characters, like this:

```
VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/qa/%-3.-12+/members
```

The url would be something like `namespace-members-qa.server.com`

I'm expecting the above to interpolated as `/var/www/qa/namespace`, but it ends up being interpolated as `/var/www/qa/a2+`, because it's parsing the -12+ as -1 and then 2+.

Is there an easy way to let apache know that I mean -12 and not -1 and 2?

Thanks in advance.